# Save SQL query to variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have written a PL/PgSQL trigger and i need to save the query (in fact the result set) to variable.
See below:

```
DECLARE
    __query record;
    r record;
BEGIN
    __query := (SELECT * FROM posts);
    FOR r IN __query LOOP
        -- do something with the row data
    END LOOP;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

**Which data type for query itself should i use?**

I guess `record` is not appropriate data type and should be used in the loop cycle itself (for r var).

Comment: i believe you should use cursor here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to pass the query for the loop as a character variable, then you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE 
    _query : text;
    r : record;
BEGIN
    _query := 'SELECT * FROM posts';

    FOR r IN EXECUTE _query LOOP
       -- do stuff
    END LOOP;

    RETURN new;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR cursor is (select * from posts);
  r      record;
BEGIN

FOR cursor_rec in cursor LOOP
  ... 
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE

  cursor c is select * from posts;
  -- r  record; you don't need to declare this variable
BEGIN
   FOR c_rec in c LOOP
       ... 
       ... 
       ... 
   END LOOP;
END;
```

this code for oracle pl-sql